# Preventing accidental deletion of storage bucket

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

how can I prevent the accidental deletion of a bucket? I've enabled versioning to prevent the accidental deletion of objects, but if someone just deletes the whole bucket, my data is down the drain, right? I've read upon the retention policy and locking it, but then I would need to disable object versioning. I could implement the following:

- create a different project where the bucket will live and have no storage admin there (just the owner of the project)
- mirror the bucket to another bucket with retention policy set

Any other options that I could implement?

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 4):

Add a Retention Policy to the bucket and then lock the retention policy. This prevents a bucket from being deleted until all objects have exceeded the retention period.

[Retention policies and retention policy locks](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/bucket-lock)

> You can add a retention policy to a bucket to specify a retention
> period.
>
> - If a bucket does not have a retention policy, you can delete or replace objects in the bucket at any time.
> - If a bucket has a retention policy, objects in the bucket can only be deleted or replaced once their age is greater than the retention
>   period.
> - A retention policy retroactively applies to existing objects in the bucket as well as new objects added to the bucket.
> - You can lock a retention policy to permanently set it on the bucket.
>
> Once you lock a retention policy, you cannot remove it or reduce the
> retention period it has.
>
> - You cannot delete a bucket with a locked retention policy unless every object in the bucket has met the retention period.
> - You can increase the retention period of a locked retention policy.
> - Locking a retention policy can help your data comply with record retention regulations.

Comment: I would really like to keep the object versioning, but from what I’ve read they are mutually exclusive, retention policy and object versioning. Or did this change?

Comment: @ChristianvanderLeeden Correct, they are mutually exclusive. Retention policies prevent an object from being deleted, so how could you have multiple versions? Compare the features this way **Cloud Storage retains a noncurrent object version each time you replace or delete a live object version, as long as you do not specify the generation number of the live version.** Objects in Cloud Storage are immutable, which means to modify an object you **replace** the existing object with a new one. Replace means delete the original and upload a new object.

Comment: That is understood. So if I want to keep object versioning (to be able to guard against accidental deletes), I can’t switch to retention policy. My current object versioning and lifecycle setup will delete the object after it is 30 days noncurrent. So the solution to switch to retention policy is not an option for me. Have to think of something else then…

Comment: @ChristianvanderLeeden - You only have two options, you can only select one. Your question has been answered.

Answer (score 3):

The solution to my problem was to implement a deny policy and deny the `storage.buckets.delete` permission for the whole project. See also https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/deny-overview.

Comment: Nice. Would you be able to share some more information on the deny policy you have implemented? Have yo uattached it to all users (but then, in case you need to actually delete a bucket, you have to touch the policy) or how did you structure it? Thanks!

Comment: I had it on the organization. But, since I wanted to have expiring access I ended up rolling a set of google predefined roles into one custom role (through terraform). There, I removed the storage.buckets.delete permission. You are right though, that it can be a pain if you need to delete the bucket. I thought about adding conditions to the policy (e.g. only deny on certain bucket names) but didn't implement it then.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I ended up applying it to the project which contains production resources, so I can keep test buckets in a different one.